# Ignore hidden rows and stop macro after 10 empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following macro to translate selected cells with Google Translate.

It works like a charm but I also want it to ignore hidden rows and make sure it stops after 10 empty cells.

Also, linebreaks are removed in the translated cell for some reason, which I actually want to keep.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub Translate()
    Dim getParam As String, trans As String, translateFrom As String, translateTo As String
    translateFrom = "en"
    translateTo = "fr"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim blanks As Long

    For Each cell In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If blanks > 10 Then Exit For

    If cell.Value = "" Then
        blanks = blanks + 1
    Else

        getParam = ConvertToGet(cell.Value)
        URL = "https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
        objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.send ("")

        If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
            trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
            cell.Value = Clean(trans)
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cell.Font.Color = Black
            Cells.ClearComments
        End If

    End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: just test if `cell.value` is empty and only translate if it is not empty. You haven't showed what you have tried to achieve your goal. Line breaks are probabley removed because you cannot have line breaks in an URL. • For stopping after 10 empty cells increase a counter everytime `cell.value` is empty and if it reaches 10 `Exit Sub`. • Give it a try.

Comment: You want it to stop after 10 hidden cells or 10 empty cells?

Comment: I want it to stop after 10 empty cells and ignore any hidden rows

Comment: Delete the line `Set cell = Selection` and try your code again with the changes from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code you can use that meets both of your criteria:

1. Only loop through visible cells *(`xlCellTypeVisible`)*
2. Stop code *(`Exit For`)* after 10 blank cells have been found during loop

*Note the blanks must be visible to be considered here*

Your action statements would go in place of `Debug.Print rng.Value` in the sample code provided below

---

```
Sub Shelter_In_Place()

Dim cell As Range
Dim blanks As Long

For Each cell In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If blanks > 10 Then Exit For
    'Depending on your actual code, you may need to use 'Exit Sub' instead

    If cell.Value = "" Then
        blanks = blanks + 1
    Else

        getParam = ConvertToGet(cell.Value)
        URL = "https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
        objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.send ("")

        If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
            trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
            cell.Value = Clean(trans)
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cell.Font.Color = Black
            Cells.ClearComments
        End If

    End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks urdearboy. I applied the changes to my code according to your comment but without success unfortunately.

Comment: This is tested and working for me. Will need to give more details on what is not working else I can't help you

Comment: I updated my code using your actual code. You were meant to replace your loop with the loop I created as a sample. You nested your loop inside my loop which is def not going to work. Try this and let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, it works but only when 2 cells or more are selected. When only one cell is selected, the macro will simply ignore it and process the first cells in the sheet instead. I can't post the revised code here in this comment cause it's too long, so I edited my original one with your changes. Thanks again.